# suitlet max lines and paging

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I need to create a suitlet where according to criteria, I will show transactions like invoice, bill, journal, ...
The Goal is to make a custom GL matching page with many results.
I know that a search can return maximum 4000 results.
I also know that the laptop from the user can freeze if the number of results is above 500 on the page.
Is there a way to make paging and let the user click on a next or before button to load 500 results by 500 results?
I saw that there was a way with paging and saving the page in the parameter but it isn't ok because the goal after is to trigger a scheduled or map/reduce script to process the selection.
Or maybe use cache to save the selected one?
I wanted to make a sort of SPA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this client side by utilizing RESTlets and good old fashioned HTML CSS and JavaScript.

To do this, you will have to have a suitelet that will return HTML when depending on the parameters it's passed or return JSON. For this to work you will have to use JavaScript running on the client to fetch data from the same Suitelet that the HTML is served on to avoid any issues with CORS, etc. and update the DOM using the results of the API call and JavaScript. You can also use this method to trigger your Map/Reduce script in the same way you would get paged saved search results.

It's kind of complicated because you have to do everything from scratch instead of using NetSuite's native serverWidet module, but doing it this way will allow you to build whatever you want.

example restlet get function

```js
    const get = ({page: pageIndex}) => {
        const PAGE_SIZE = 50; // change this to be whatever page size you want to up to 500
        
        // add other filters and columns, etc. that make sense for your use case
        const ss = search.create({
            type: "employee", // w/e record type you want here
        });
        
        const pagedResults = ss.runPaged({pageSize: PAGE_SIZE});

        // use this to know what pages are available to iterate over 
        const numPages = Math.ceil(pagedResults.count / PAGE_SIZE);
        
        let page = pagedResults.fetch({index: pageIndex});

        const data = [];
        page.data.forEach((result) => {
            // build your data you want to return from the restlet
            data.push(result.id);
        });
        
        return JSON.stringify({
            data,
            currentPage: pageIndex,
            pageCount: numPages,
        });
    }
```

example javascript used on the client to manage the state of what rows are selected and their associated data

```js
      const selectedItems = [];
      let currentPageIndex = 0; // this will have to be updated whenever you change pages
      
      // a similar event listener should be added to your checkbox elements to allow you 
      // to store information about the rows selected
      const handleCheckboxCheck = (e) => {
        const rowIdx = 1; // get this from the dom
        if (e.target.checked) {
          // add the selected to the state
          selectedItems.push({
            data: {
              /** information you would like to keep record of goes here */
            },
            rowIdx,
            pageIdx: currentPageIndex,
          });
        } else {
          // remove the selected from state
          const idx = selectedItems.findIndex(
            (v) => v.rowIdx == rowIdx && v.pageIdx == currentPageIndex
          );
          selectedItems.splice(idx, 1);
        }
      };
```

Comment: And how do you handle the state? If they decide to mark some line, how do you save the state?

Comment: In the example I gave, it would have to be done on client-side. You said you want to make an SPA and RESTlets and inherently stateless. So if you wanted to go this route, you would have to use whatever way makes the most sense to you to manage state on the client. 

I could tell you how to implement what you're looking for using a Suitelet alone, but it wouldn't be an SPA and you would have to submit the form to page through sublist results which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: If you really wanted to do this, I would add an event listener to whatever checkbox field you implement to append or remove the results of that row to an object or array to keep the selections, then when you paginate through the sublists, you'll need to memoize the results from the previous page so that you don't have to make an API request you've already made before.